# sendUserNotification issue on Android ("No Activity found to handle Intent")

Tags: detox

I'm attempting to use sentUserNotification on Android and I get the error below.

> Test Failed: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x24000000 pkg=com.******.******.****** (has extras) }

Is this something someone here has ran into before? I think my app is set up correctly (e.g. manifest has intent filter) but I'm wondering if there's something else I missed.

I'm on Detox v17.11.4.

Comment: Sorry to bump an old thread. Did you ever find a solution to this? Currently getting the exact same error.